# How to differentiate $f(x)=z^i$

Tags: complex-analysis, implicit-differentiation

I have a question to solve which goes like this: Find the derivative of the principal value $z^i$ at the point $z=(1 + i)$.

So far I have put $z$ into exponential form so $z=re^{i\theta}$, then after taking it to i'th power and differentiating it I got $f'(x)=i \frac{z^i}{|z|} - z^i$ but now Im stuck

Perhaps I went in a wrong direction initially

Comment: You haven't used the "the principal value" yet.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $f(z)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The (branches of the) complex logarithm are defined by $(\log z)'=1/z$. Since you are only interested in a single point, we can safely differentiate:

$$f(z)=z^i=\exp(i\log z)\quad\implies\quad f'(z)=i\exp(i\log z)\cdot\frac1z=iz^{i-1}.$$

Comment: is it safe to take log(z) considering it is a complex number?

Comment: @user6396911 Somehow. If we restrict to a single [branch of the complex logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#Branches_of_the_complex_logarithm) it works as any function that you can differentiate. Since we only work in a single point and not on a whole set of complex numbers, we are safe to do this. Differentiating $\log z$ behaves the same no matter what branch we have chosen. On the principal branch, if you stay away from zero and the negative reals, you are safe anyway.

Comment: so presumably to find the end result I have to substitute z with (1+i) but then there will be a (1-i) power, is it possible to do anything about it?

one more question if you dont mind, what does 'derivative of a principal value mean?

Comment: @user6396911 If you substitute $z=i+1$, you will have an exponent of $i$. There spawned quite a lot of videos on this topic on youtube in the last months, e.g. [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9tlHQOKMHGA). To the other question: The complex logarithm (and with it also $z^i$) can be defined in several ways (I recommend reading the Wiki article linked above). Each way might give a different result to your task. But there is a preferred definition, which is called the principal branch of $\log z$. "derivative of a principal value" means you use this definition when differentiating.

Comment: @M.Winter isn't this more of a coincidence. The derivative of the principle square root, does not follow the usual rule. $F^2(z)=z$ follows by diff. both sides  $F'(z)=\frac{1}{2F(z)}=\frac{1}{2\{\sqrt{z}\}}$

Comment: @AlexanderCska Sorry I do not completely understand. What is a coincidence? What is the "usual rule" that is not followed by the principal square root.

Comment: @M.Winter here is a second attempt :). Suppose we had $\left( z^3(3-z)\right)^{\frac{1}{4}}$. What I would do is, use the fact that for the principle branch $\left(F(z)\right)^4=z^3(3-z)$ holds, differentiate both sides and get $F'(z)=\frac{(9-4z)F(z)}{4z(3-z)}$.
Why is this step needed, can't i just do ordinary calculus  $\frac{d\left( z^3(3-z)\right)^{\frac{1}{4}}}{dz}=\frac{(9 - 4 z) z^2}{4 ((3 - z) z^3)^{\frac{3}{4}}}$, which is exactly the same after simplifying?

Comment: @AlexanderCska It was a long time ago that I made that post, but I think my intentions were as follows: the result of differentiating might be different for different branches (e.g. in you $z^4$ example you can determine the brach by looking at the derivative). I think the first paragraph is there to shortly mention that this is not the case for the logarithm and we have the same derivative for all branches. However, I think the main reason for this level of detail was because OP explicitly mentioned "principal branch" in the question.

Comment: So basically, the same rules for differentiation from ordinary calculus hold as well for the principle branches.

Comment: @AlexanderCska I would say Yes, as in my head "principal branches" are made to look like ordinary calculus.